# c multiple indirection - assigning a char** to an array of char*

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, multiple-indirection

A `char**` is a pointer to a `char*`. This means that the value of a `char**` is the address of a `char*`. The value of a `char*` is the address of the first element in a character array stored in memory.

So in the code below:

- `char* words[3];` is an array of 3 pointers to character arrays, aka `char*`.
- `char** ppc;` is a pointer to a `char*`

My question is how can you assign `ppc = words` when `words` is an array of `char*`s.

```
char* words[LENGTH];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  char** ppc;

  words[0] = "one";
  words[1] = "two";
  words[2] = "three";

  for (int i =0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", words[i]);
  }

  ppc = words; 

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Good ol' fashioned *decay to a pointer*.

Comment: If you use an array when a pointer is expected, then the array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element. In your case, when you use `ppc = words` what the compiler generates is really `ppc = &words[0]`.

Comment: ah thank you I should of understood that.

Comment: Any C pointer can point to a single item or an array of items.  Your post suggests that you somehow think `char *` always points to an array, and `char **` never does.  That distinction is false.  Either can point to an array, and neither has to.

Comment: @TomKarzes, thanks Tom, yes I have written that poorly. What your saying is that a `char*` can point to just a single `char` or an array of `char`s? And `char**` can point to a single `char*` or an array of `char**`s. Is that correct?

Comment: @articsol Right.  Strictly speaking, they point to a single item, but by adding an integer offset to them, they can point to successive elements in an array.

Comment: @TomKarzes I agree you are correct strictly speaking they point to a single item. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In most contexts, an array can *decay* to a pointer to the first element of the array.

In this example, `words` is an array of pointers to `char`, i.e. it has type `char *[]`.  An element of this array has type `char *`, so `ppc = words` assigns `&words[0]`, which has type `char **`, to `ppc`.